# Shall I ask HR about my test schedule?

Tags: communication, new-job, hiring-process

Currently I'm an Intern at a company, and last week, HR asked if I was interested in taking the test to become a full time employee and I said I was interested. HR said that the test would be held at November 16-17, which is tomorrow, and I will receive further details next week (which mean this week).

But to this day, I haven't received further information, should I ask HR about confirming my test schedule? My HR is so busy that I am afraid that she forgot about it, and if I have to, what are the right words to talk to her

UPDATE:
Already call HR about my test schedule and it will be start at 19-20 Nov ,because the invitation email to take the test was not sent yesterday to all interns who will participate the test .

Comment: I edited your question to make it more readable, though I am not sure the last sentence in the first paragraph is what you wanted to say. Please feel free to undo the edit if this interpretation was wrong.

Comment: "Hey, I'm just calling to confirm my test scheduled for tomorrow." Call over the phone since it's pretty urgent.

Comment: @Lehue thanks for the edit , it wasnt wrong and has a better grammar than i did , appreciate it!

Comment: Does the rest of the company work better than HR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, reach out to the HR about the update. In my opinion, the best time to do that was yesterday, do it as soon as possible.

As a professional, you need to know how to **follow up** things / activities. Consider this as a part of your training.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer ,  i will ask her now

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, since you are interested in becoming a full time employee, you should ask about the test.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer ,  i will ask her now

Comment: Please let us know how it goes. Good luck

Comment: hehe i already update it in the question , it goes well and the test was postponed and be held at 19-20 November , because yesterday the invitation email wasn't sent to all interns who participating in the test

Comment: Good luck with it. I hope you get the job :-)

Comment: Thankyou , i will do my best for it! ^^

Comment: should i follow up again about the test for tomorrow or not? im just scared about making her pissed off

Comment: I think by now it should be ok. She will surely have updated her email list to include all of the interns (?) Anyone half competent would have. If it happens twice, someone will inform her boss, so she is very motivated to get it right this time

Comment: okay , i will wait until test day,  thankyouu!!